# Is there a nice/clean way to read a plist file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, plist

After my web application has loaded onto the screen, I am trying to send an AJAX request via JQuery for a different plist file.

I understand that AJAX treats plist files somewhat similar to XML files, but I was wondering if there is a third party parser out there that will help me break down the various 'array' and 'dict' tags?

Otherwise if someone else knows an easier way of reading data out of a plist file in JavaScript, it would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a library for that, try it out (i haven't so don't hold me to it)

Try it out: https://github.com/pugetive/plist_parser